# UIWebView redraws on view did appear, how can I prevent this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

I am working on a app using `UIWebView` now getting a issue **listed below** please help me to sort it out.

- In my UIWebView, I show some HTML content from String in it.
- **However, when I go to another `ViewController` and return back, it goes white for a second then draws my HTML content again.**

Is there any way to prevent this? My html content does not change, so can I set it as fixed content or something to draw it faster ?

This is how I set html in webview:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlData, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: Do you destroy your webview when you change view controller?

Comment: Show the code where you are loading html coten in webview

Comment: webView.loadHTMLString(htmlData, baseURL: nil)

Comment: Could you show us (by editing your question) how ans when (in which method) your are loading your content in the webview ?

Comment: I am setting the UIWebView content in a UITableViewCell. So I call the method in: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTMl code is not changing, so that put your `webView` load code inside `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewDidAppear`, because `viewDidAppear` always call when your `view` is appear, where as `viewDidLoad` called single time when your `view` is load.

Comment: The UIWebView is in a UITableViewCell. So I am calling it in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @TheCook Then you are reloading the `tableView` inside `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`, check that and reload the data in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: What should I do to fix it ?

Comment: Check my above comment properly. if you are calling `tableView.reloadData` inside `viewDidAppear` then remove from there and put it inside `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Wow that was actually the case! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*you can execute the code which is directing webview once in a life cycle of app or customize accordingly.*

```
// if you are navigating your application using navigation controller enables you to come back to the rootview without executing whole code of that class associated with view.
// this doesn't apply the whole life cycle of view controller
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

// if you navigating through below code this apply the whole life cycle concept of view controller.
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

> you must have a look about the life cycle of view controller here  is a useful [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html)

**viewController Life cycle short note**

- ViewDidLoad - Called when you create the class and load from xib. Great for initial setup and one-time-only work.
- ViewWillAppear - Called right before your view appears, good for hiding/showing fields or any operations that you want to happen every time before the view is visible. Because you might be going back and forth between views, this will be called every time your view is about to appear on the screen.
- ViewDidAppear - Called after the view appears - great place to start an animations or the loading of external data from an API.
- ViewWillDisappear/DidDisappear - Same idea as ViewWillAppear/ViewDidAppear.
- ViewDidUnload/ViewDidDispose - In Objective C, this is where you do your clean-up and release of stuff, but this is handled automatically so not much you really need to do here.